# Triangle draws in wrong place before window resize?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut, gltools

The position of the triangle displayed when the program is first opened is not the same as expected.  Then I changed the window size and the triangles were displayed in the correct position.

How can I modify the code so that the triangle appears in the right place when the program starts running?

This is my screenshot, showing the error:

[image: screenshot of behavior]

Code below:

```cpp
#include <GLTools.h>            // OpenGL toolkit
#include <GLShaderManager.h>    // Shader Manager Class

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h>          // OS X version of GLUT
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h>            // Windows FreeGlut equivalent
#endif

GLBatch triangleBatch;
GLShaderManager shaderManager;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Window has changed size, or has just been created. In either case, we need
// to use the window dimensions to set the viewport and the projection matrix.
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
    {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering context. 
// This is the first opportunity to do any OpenGL related tasks.
void SetupRC()
    {
    // Blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

    // Load up a triangle
    GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                          0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };

    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    triangleBatch.End();
    }



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
    {
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vRed);
    triangleBatch.Draw();

    // Perform the buffer swap to display back buffer
    glutSwapBuffers();
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main entry point for GLUT based programs
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Triangle");
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
        }

    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;   
}
```

My environment is Xcode11.3 in macOS 10.15.1.

Comment: Set the viewport rectangle by `glViewport` before `glutMainLoop`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have tried it, but unfortunately not.

Comment: I have seen other students running this code online, but their results are correct. I suspect it has something to do with my Xcode13.1 or macOS10.15

Comment: What happens when you set the viewport before the main loop? Does it change anything or nothing? Because that seems wrong.

Comment: @churill The problem now is that setting the `viewport` for the first time does not work. The `viewport` only works when I manually change the window size. the program will definitely call the `ChangeSize()` method for the first time automatically, but this call did not meet the expectations.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Just `glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);` before `glutMainLoop()` changes nothing?

Comment: @churill This is my screenshot:https://i.loli.net/2019/12/19/joBledmAwUhYKZV.png. There are two pictures in the screenshot. The picture on the left is what the program looks like when it is opened. Although my `glViewport` is `(0, 0, 800, 600)`, this position is obviously wrong. If I manually change the window size, it will look like the right picture in the screenshot, and the position will be correct.So why is the display wrong when the program starts?

Comment: @churill  glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600); before glutMainLoop() .Change nothing. I have tried it.

Comment: If you print out the window size when it's resized, and resize it slightly, is it close to 800x600?

Comment: Kinda looks like HiDPI shenanigans.  Anything change if you disable display scaling in macOS?

Comment: Can you try calling your resize/viewport function right after glutCreateWindow("Triangle");

Comment: It seems it needs a "manual" resize before the first render. Use `glutReshapeWindow` just before `glutMainLoop`

Comment: @genpfault Nice! You are right! Thank U! This problem was solved after I disabled the display scaling！ Can you tell me why? Why it has to do with the display scaling？